# How can I build a bubble chart in Plotly with bubble size based on how large an intersection is?

Tags: python, plotly, bubble-chart

So I'm trying to visualize intersections of a bunch of columns with a bubble chart. I began with a simple scatter plot, but realized I was missing how prevalent any given intersection is in the data. Scatter plot only tells that there is an intersection. I'll use pseudo boolean columns as a simple example, but this applies to any categorical data:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px    
data_temp = pd.DataFrame({'bool_col_1': [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1], 
                          'bool_col_2': [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1]})
fig = px.scatter(data_temp, x='bool_col_1', y='bool_col_2')
fig.show()
```

This outputs something that looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFgHO.png).

As you can probably tell, this scatter plot doesn't tell me how much of the data intersects at the point where, for example, both values are '1', it only tells me that there's at least one row in the dataframe where that's the case.

I want to build a bubble chart that would dynamically  determine the size of every dot in the plot based on how prevalent is the intersection of the data that a dot represents. So far I haven't been able to find a way to to that in Plotly's express or graph_objects modules (and it has to be Plotly). Every guide out there only covers how to determine bubble size based on one certain column.

Answer (score 0):

- this is effectively a histogram.
- in **pandas** `value_counts()` generates the counts
- in **plotly** `size` parameter references column from **pandas**
- have changed both axis to be categorical

```
px.scatter(
    data_temp.value_counts().reset_index(), x="bool_col_1", y="bool_col_2", size=0
).update_layout({ax:{"type": "category"} for ax in ["xaxis","yaxis"]})
```

[image]